# @JsonView how to use with @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to add JsonView functionality to control input of my application. And I find that I can use this annotation with RequestBody in Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE but get error this annotation not allowed here

```
 public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                                         @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey,
                                         @JsonView(View.Summary.class) @RequestBody User user) throws Exception{
```

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using? According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-annotations/issues/48) `@JsonView` is supported on method parameters since 2.5. Also this [Spring issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12501) shows that it was implemented in Spring 4.2.RC1 not 4.1.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt 2.2.3 and now I change it to 2.5 and it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) annotation is supported on method parameters since version 2.5 of Jackson. You must therefore upgrade your Jackson dependency for it to work.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-annotations/issues/48)